# Deleting a filter from a view in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I've inherited some websites. In Google Analytics, some have filters attached to them as a view - which is filtering out all traffic. How do I delete these?! In Admin > View > Filters, there is no delete button. When I try to change the filter, there's no save button, but if I navigate away from the page, an alert pops up saying "Your changes have not been saved". How on earth do I alter the view? Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics has two permissions levels which are;

**1. Edit Permissions at account level**

**2. Edit permission at view level**

From your statement, it is clear you have been given the 'edit permissions at account' level since you dont have the options to delete at views level. This is due to the fact that you inherited the account and the main admin hasn't given you that authorizations yet.
 Kindly find more information from this link below;

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823#Permissions

Comment: Permissions are inherited from account to property to view. It's more likely that the OP hasn't the necessary permissions in the first place. Also there is no such thing as a "main admin" in GA.